# How to implement an Application with ViewPager (each view holds a layout with some keys)?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I would like to implement an application which has three screens.

All the three screens will be having three different layouts with a set of its own keys.

I would like to implement this inside a ViewPager so that i can swipe my screens, and interact with each screen as if i am interacting to an activity.

How can i do this?

One of my colleagues told me i need to get the id of all the buttons and views used and should interact to it separately. I dint understand that. Could somebody explain the logic to implement this application to me.

I would like to implement something like the launcher in tablet or phone. Does the touch listener be able to make a click on the view or widget lying on the screen below my touch point?

Please find the figures of my app.

[image: Figure-1. Default View of the Application with one screen highlighted in the Screen. The side screens just give an idea that there are screens to the sides.]

[image: Figure-2. When the screen was swiped to the Right.]

[image: Figure-3. When the screen was swiped to the Left.]

All the screens has some buttons and widgets which need to respond to the user touch/click when each is highlighted.

Please shed some light into this.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to create a dashboard, similar to some devices' default launchers, by implementing ViewPager and creating my own PagerAdpter. See the code below:

```
public class DashboardPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private static final int ROWS = 4;
private static final int COLS = 4;

private Context mContext;
private List<AppEntry> mData;

public DashboardPagerAdapter(Context context, List<AppEntry> data) {
    mContext = context;
    mData = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    double ratio = (double) mData.size() / (ROWS * COLS);
    return (int) Math.ceil(ratio);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((TableLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    int cols = COLS, rows = ROWS;
    switch (mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
        rows++;
        break;
    default:
        cols++;
    }

    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(mContext);
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    table.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    table.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

    int start = position * rows * cols;
    int end = Math.min(start + rows * cols, mData.size());

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(mContext);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

            int pos = start + i * cols + j;

            if (pos < end) {

                AppEntry item = mData.get(pos);

                View vItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null,
                        false);

                ImageView image = (ImageView) vItem.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                image.setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());

                row.addView(vItem);
            } else {
                TextView vPlaceHolder = new TextView(mContext);
                vPlaceHolder.setText(" ");
                row.addView(vPlaceHolder);
            }

        }
        table.addView(row);
    }

    container.addView(table);

    return table;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}
```

}

The instantiateItem method, in this case, returns a TableLayout which I use to display the app icons. I calculate the number of pages (getCount()) by dividing the size of the collection of data by the number of items per page (rows * cols).

You could add an onClickListener to vItem inside the for loop in case you want to handle that event. I would recommend to share the listener between the views and ask for the tag or ID before taking any action.

If your content is static, you would probably want to use FragmentPagerAdapter instead, and create one Fragment for each page.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly ambitious -- otherwise everyone would have already released their own launcher-style application -- but doable. Sounds like you need a `ViewPager` with [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) as the hosted view. The `GridView` can easily do the things you're talking about with a `onItemClickListener()` attached to it to capture clicks on each item. There are a lot of tutorials out there for `ViewPager` (see [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) for a decent one) and `GridView` (see [here](http://www.firstdroid.com/2011/02/06/android-tutorial-gridview-with-icon-and-text/) for a decent one of *those*), now all you need to do is get them working together which should be too tough given a little work.